# Gremlin-driver cannot get repsponse from titandb

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to query a server titan instance via WebSockets using gremlin-driver.
so I have next dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

Trying to get a value using next command:

```
       List<Result> some = client.submit("g.V().has(T.label, marketplace).has('marketplace_product_id', marketplace_product_id)", params).some(1).get();
```

And getting next exception:

```
 WARN  o.a.t.g.driver.MessageSerializer - Response [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 136, widx: 136, cap: 136)] could not be deserialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0.
13:41:36.879 [gremlin-driver-loop-1] ERROR o.a.t.g.d.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler - Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 0
```

Didn't found a workable example over the web about CRUD actions using gremlin-driver.
Does anyone know how to deal with that?

Edit 1:
Using titan-1.0.0-hadoop1
Tried also with driver version 3.0.1-incubating and got almost the same IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: What version of Titan are you using?

Comment: If you're using Titan version 1.0, probably you need to use gremlin driver with  version `3.0.1-incubating`

Answer (score 1):

try this: May be it will help

```
List<Result> some = null; 
some = client.submit("g.V()
                 .has(T.label,marketplace)
                 .has('marketplace_product_id', marketplace_product_id)")
             .stream()**
             .map(r -> r.get(Vertex.class))**
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```